# Android Progress Dialog Does Not Dismiss at times when used with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am making a REST API Call using volley in my android app. The code works most of the times. However, there are occasions where the progress dialog does not dismiss and I need to restart the app. What am I doing wrong? Code below. Thanks

```
private void getServerCountsForLocation(JSONObject mDataPacket) {

    String url = REST_API_END_POINT + "GetServerCounts/";

    if (myApp.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Getting total counts", false);

        //call the rest api
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, url, mDataPacket, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        parseResponseForServerCounts(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        renderView();
                    }
                });
        jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3000, 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue().add(jsObjRequest);
    } else {
        Log.print("Network connection not available in DeviceCountActivity for total counts query");
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(DeviceCountActivity.this, "Network connection unavailable. Please try again after connecting with WiFi or SIM.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well it's obvious it's not problem of the dialog.It's just your onResponse is not called at those times.Are you using a local server or online?It could be your server problem obviously.Put a log statement in onResponse and find the problem.And it's okay you always don't expect the server to respond.So you should handle those cases.Your information is not enough.You're saying sometimes it doesn't work.You should find when it doesn't and mention it.

Comment: Can you post full code? @Crazy

Comment: @Steve. That is correct - dialog is not the issue. I also dismiss the dialog both in onResponse and onError. Control does not go to either clause. Hence, the dialog is never dismissed. Two possibilities - Either the volley call is never made for whatever reason or volley request is fired but it does not get a response or an error.

Comment: @Brahma - Thanks. What other code did you have in mind?

Comment: As I remember with volley you get the error on timeout also.So it should give you the error.Maybe you're not getting the error because of using setRetryPolicy.Delete this line an try again maybe?